# Using ledger wallet to create Candy Machine

Tags: metaplex, nft, wallet, candy-machine-v2, ledger

Metaplex docs says that I can create a new wallet with solana CLI to be used on CM creation. This is the command to set it as default wallet:

`solana config set --keypair ~/.config/solana/devnet.json`

Is there a way to use a wallet created from my ledger?

What I want to achieve is to pay the CM creation with that wallet to avoid moving funds to other not-ledger wallet. Creator and solTreasuryAccount have to be the same.

Will the ledger ask me to confirm the transaction for each NFT during upload phase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to use the guide here from solana docs? https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/hardware-wallets/ledger

1. Ensure the Ledger Live application is closed
2. Plug your Nano into your computer's USB port
3. Enter your pin and start the Solana app on the Nano
4. Ensure the screen reads "Application is ready

Accessing the publey then works like this:
solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger
solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger?key=0
solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger?key=1
solana-keygen pubkey usb://ledger?key=2
…

I expect that if you set it in the solana cli accordingly sugar will work, too.

Edit to answer your last question: if it works You will have to sign a huge amount of transactions. Some for the upload, and then many for the config lines

Comment: Yes, this probably solve my question of how to use ledger wallet, but it seems not reliable if I need to sign a huge quantity of mini transactions. Better to use another wallet just to pay the CM creation and set the ledger wallet as treasury account to receive selling and fee funds there

Comment: Yes, for me it would not be worth it. Technically you could create the CM and then hand over the authority to the ledger to be a bit more safe

Answer (score 0):

The correct format to target a specific account on your Ledger, per Solana CLI docs, is:

```
usb://ledger/accountredacted\?key=1
```

You can retrive this path using the Solana CLI **resolve-signer** command:

```
solana resolve-signer usb://ledger?key=0/0
```

Unfortunately, the Ledger will not read/sign with candy machine commands. I have been looking for a fix for this and cannot find any solution.

This is the error that persists:

```
 Error running command (re-run needed): Failed to read keypair file: usb://ledger/accountredacted/?key=1, No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

However, this could be related to zsh terminal issue. Anyone with a deeper understanding of this issue hopefully can contribute here.

**Note**: Make sure where `\?key=1` is that you use the correct key (derivation path) location on your Ledger.

Also, my listed command is formatted for macOS (with zsh fix) terminal, you can drop the `\` for other terminals if I'm not mistaken. Confirm here for reference: [Keypair URL parameters are ignored in zsh](https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/hardware-wallets/ledger#keypair-url-parameters-are-ignored-in-zsh)

### Update

Looks like Metaplex does not support Ledger based signing. Ref here: [[Bug]: Sugar sign does not work with ledger wallet #416](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/sugar/issues/416)

Hopefully this is supported soon as security provided by hardware wallet could be very critical for certain NFT based applications.